# PHP script via terminal is stopping while querying mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, runtime-error, command-line-interface

I've got this problem running the following script by linux terminal:
the first *echo* it's ok, it shows me also the *frwite*, but after it i write somethin as requested and script doesn't do anything!
The mysql query doesn't work, maybe 'cause the database is online and not in my pc?
If you can help me, i will be so happy :)
Thanks.

```
<?php
// stampo la data a video
echo "Oggi è il ".date("d M Y.. (h:i:s)", time())."\nScript by Ludovico Loreti\n";
// Chiedo il numero di giorni su cui vuole essere aggiornato
fwrite(STDOUT, "Numero di giorni sui quali vuoi essere aggiornato: ");
$num_giorni = trim(fgets(STDIN));
// Definisco le variabili host user pass per la connessione
$db_host = "HOST";
$db_user = "USER";
$db_pass = "PASSWD";
$db_database = "DB_NAME";

// Connessione al database
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die(mysql_error()); 


$timestampGiorni = $num_giorni*86400;
// Creo la query per la quale devo avere dei risultati
$primaQuery = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE ".time()." - regdate 
<= '".$timestampGiorni."'";
if (mysql_num_rows($primaQuery) == 0) 
{ // se la query non ha prodotto risultati
    fwrite(STDOUT, "Nessun utente si è registrato negli ultimi 
$num_giorni giorni");
}
 else
{ // se invece sono presenti dei risultati
    while ($temp=mysql_fetch_array($primaQuery))  
        { // stampami i risultati per ogni riga
            echo "Nome utente: ".$temp['username']."\n Indirizzo Mail: "
            .$temp['email']."\n 
 Nome Attività: ".$temp['companyname']."\n
            --------------------------------------------------\n";
        }
}
?>
```

mysql error:
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (4) in /bla/bla/script.php on line 14

Comment: Consider change to mysqli, rather then use mysql.

Comment: ehm i've always used mysql, i don't like to change now, its difficult to learn now...

Comment: now it gives me an error:
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (4) in /bla/bla/script.php on line 14